# Rails post xml to secure web service api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, builder, net-http

I am trying to use rails 4.0 to create an API for a web service which requires a direct xml post to their secure server.

I have a form which submits the `:action => "testSubmit" to trigger the following code in my controller, which I've pieced together after hours of (mostly outdated) research and debugging.

```
def testSubmit

  xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
  xml.instruct!
  xml.sale do
    xml.tag! 'tag-1', "INFO_HERE"
    xml.tag! 'tag-2', "MORE_INFO"
    xml.amount "100.00"
  end

  uri = URI('https://secure.abc.com')

  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
    :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    response = http.post("/api/some/path", xml.to_s)
    flash[:notice] = "Sent?"
  end    



end
```

The rails framework does redirect to the `testSubmit.html.erb` view, with the `flash` present, so everything indicates that it may be working, but if I try to read the response data it appears to be empty. For instance if I include `<%= response %>` in my view, I see:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Response:0x007fd167ddef60>
```

but `<%= response.body %>` renders nothing...

I expect the response to be specific xml, which I have verified using PHP and Curl, as well as the firefox add-on "Poster"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. Working code below.

```
 def testSubmit

      xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
      xml.instruct!
      xml.sale do
        xml.tag! 'tag-1', "INFO_HERE"
        xml.tag! 'tag-2', "MORE_INFO"
        xml.amount "100.00"
      end

      uri = URI('https://secure.abc.com')

      Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
        :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
        @xml = xml.target!
        @response = http.post(uri.path, @xml, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'text/xml'})
        flash[:notice] = "Sent?"
      end    

 end
```

This:  `<%= @response.body %>` Works fine...